# Avoiding auto_postback using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

```
=====================================================
= Top Div              (header/menu)                =
=====================================================
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
= Left Div      =  Right Div                        =
= (Navigation)  =  id = "rightdiv"                  =
=               =  (Displays content loaded by      =
=               =   Ajax from the links in the      =
=               =   left div)                       =
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
=====================================================
```

I am new to ASP.NET development. I am trying to open a web-form in a div after submitting data to server but my form is opening in new window how can i avoid this.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: provide some code what you have done so far...

Comment: check $.load method of jquery ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an auto postback that means you're taking some action that's causing your form to submit. If you want this action to instead show a pop-up, you should prevent the default action of the form submit with jquery.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'thewebform', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // show pop-up
});
```